# MS SQL Server Directories

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Is there a way to create directory objects in SQL Server which is equivalent to Oracle directory objects?

Comment: The closest thing SQL Server has to this is `FILESTREAM` storage, which you add with `ALTER DATABASE ... ADD FILEGROUP ... CONTAINS FILESTREAM` (and then add files to using `ADD FILE`). But this is not exactly equivalent to all use cases for `CREATE DIRECTORY` in Oracle, so it depends on what you need those directories for.

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent appears to be a [filegroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx). Regarding LOBs, in SQL Server you can specify the `textdata on` clause in the `create table` statement, so that all LOB fields in this table would be actually stored in the designated filegroup.

In addition to that, there are also [FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) and [FILETABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx), the latter built on top of the former. Depending on what you need it for, one or the other might fit.